# How do I use mod_rewrite to alter which file is fetched based on the URL's sub-domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So say I have a URL being requested:

`sub.domain/file.bin`

and I wanted this file to be fetched:

`domain/hosted/sub/file.bin`

How would I structure the rewrite directives?  I've been working on this for days, and it just gives me a headache...

The sub-domains are numerous and are added and removed often, so I'm trying to find a solution that works for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sub.domain's httpd config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+).domain
RewriteRule ^/file.bin$ http://domain/hosted/%1/file.bin
```

Comment: Hrm, getting close. How could I make the "sub" dynamic based on whatever the subdomain is in the initial url?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the home directory for `www.domain.com` is `domain/` and that - given any subdomain `sub.domain.com` - you want the files for the home directories for that sub-domain to be in `domain/hosted/sub/`

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

// If the host is just mydomain.com, do nothing more
// this is to prevent some recursion problems I've read of...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

// Otherwise strip off everything before mydomain
// And add it to the start of the request
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]

// Then prefix with 'hosted'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hosted/$1 [QSA,L]
```

You may also need a wildcard entry in your DNS or something... but I will admit DNS and htaccess mod rewrite are some of my weaker points. See also http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/138.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule !^hosted/ hosted/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```